# How to add annotations anywhere in flowchart, schemdraw

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, diagram, flowchart

I am new to Python.

I'm creating this flowchart, and I'd like to add some captions (Subtitle 1, 2 and 3) to the boxes. However, I don't know how to make such annotations.

Also, I would like to expand the area of the boxes (red, blue and green).

Please, could someone help me with this?

```
pip install schemdraw
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm

with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d.config(fontsize=14)
    d += (b := flow.Start(w=6, h=2).label('Start'))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    
    d += (step1 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 1').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step2 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 2').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step3 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 3').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step4 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 4').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step5 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 5').fill(''))
    d += flow.Arrow().down(d.unit/2)
    d += (step6 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).label('Thing 6').fill(''))
    
   
    # Activities
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step1.E)
    d += (act1 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 1').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step2.E)
    d += (act2 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 2').fill(''))

    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step3.E)
    d += (act3 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 3').fill(''))
 
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step4.E)
    d += (act4 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 4').fill(''))
    
    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step5.E)
    d += (act5 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 5').fill(''))

    d += flow.Arrow().right(d.unit/2).at(step6.E)
    d += (act6 := flow.Box(w=8, h=2).anchor('W').label('activity 6').fill(''))
 
    d += (phase1 := elm.EncircleBox([step1, step2, step3, act1, act2, act3], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('red'))
    d += (phase2 := elm.EncircleBox([step4, step5, act4, act5], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('blue'))
    d += (phase3 := elm.EncircleBox([step6, act6], padx=.8).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('green'))

    #d += elm.Label().label('Parallel',loc="top").color('red')
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add labels to the EncircleBox elements, just like any other element. But by default it will appear above the box, so you need to specify the location and a rotation of 90 degrees:

```
d += (phase1 := elm.EncircleBox([step1, step2, step3, act1, act2, act3], padx=2, pady=.5).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('red')
         .label('Subtitle 1', loc='left', rotate=90))
d += (phase2 := elm.EncircleBox([step4, step5, act4, act5], padx=2, pady=.5).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('blue')
         .label('Subtitle 2', loc='left', rotate=90))
d += (phase3 := elm.EncircleBox([step6, act6], padx=2, pady=.5).linestyle('--').linewidth(2).color('green')
         .label('Subtitle 3', loc='left', rotate=90))
```

The `padx` and `pady` parameters make the EncircleBoxes bigger in the x and y directions.

Comment: Thanks, @Collin  .  Last question: do you know how to make "Subtitle 3" bold?